# Adding a UITableView to UIVIewController's view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a UITableView as a subview to my UIViewController's view, but I am getting the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Skema_Main___Controller setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e41ce0'`

Here is my code:

Skema Main - Controller.h

```
@interface Skema_Main___Controller : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

    UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *pickerArray;

}

// property and setter
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger week;
- (void)setWeekSelected:(NSInteger) weekSelected;

//UIPicker
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pickerArray;

//TableView
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *skemaTableView;

// Main Dictionary
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary; // data

@end
```

Skema Main - Controller.m

(I removed a lot of the irrelevant stuff from here, I am also using a UIPickerView)

```
...
@synthesize skemaTableView;
...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Set picker for week
    NSLog(@" %i", self.week);
    [self generateView:self.week];

    //TableView
    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    skemaTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    skemaTableView.dataSource = self;
    skemaTableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:skemaTableView];

}
...
```

Comment: You are probably calling [self setTableViewStyle:..] instead of calling it on skemaTableView

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing `skemaTableView` as a property instead of as an instance variable:

```
self.skemaTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200)
                                                   style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.skemaTableView.dataSource = self;
self.skemaTableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.skemaTableView];
```

Comment: as a property? for what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not referencing `self` when setting up your table view.

```
[self setSkemaTableView:[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain]];
[[self skemaTableView] setDataSource:self];
[[self skemaTableView] setDelegate:self];

[self.view addSubview:[self skemaTableView]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the fundamental delegate and datasource methods in your class? I see you have them called in your .h file but you need to actually have them defined in your .m file.

At the minimum you need to include...

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

When you synthesize skemaTableView you create a getter and a setter function such as this:

```
-(UITableView *) skemaTableView
{ 
   return skemaTableView;
}

-(void)setSkemaTableView:(UITableView*)newSkemaTableView
{
  if (newSkemaTableView!= skemaTableView)
  {
      skemaTableView = newSkemaTableView;
  }
}
```

So when you try to alloc and init it in the viewDidLoad method, you are not calling the generated setSkemaTableView method. When you code this:

```
[self setSkemaTableView:[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain]];
[[self skemaTableView] setDataSource:self];
[[self skemaTableView] setDelegate:self];
```

the code calls the generated setter and the getter.